# Unexplained reputation gain. Was there just a reputation recalculation?

Tags: support, reputation

I just refreshed my page and — boom — I gained around 400 reputation points!

According to my rep history, I only earned 17 points yesterday, and did not earn anything yet today.

> [image]

After I earned the last +2 for yesterday, I had around 1,700 points. Now I suddenly have over 2,100.

Did some sort of reputation recalculation just occur?

---

#### Update 5 days later:

Seems like the pendulum has just swung the other way, and I now am down 400 points.

These reputation mood swings are getting confusing.

Comment: Short answer: yes. I don't know the long answer.

Comment: @Shog9 Just out of curiosity, do you know if this has anything to do with the recent documentation contributor corruption?

Comment: I'd say that's a reasonable guess, @Tot - you've gained somewhere around 1300 points from Docs, so there's definitely room for bugs there to cause such large swings.

Comment: @Shog9 Seems like another rep recalc happened and the unexplained 400 point gain was now reversed. These frequent reputation updates are getting confusing.

Comment: "These reputation mood swings are getting confusing." - What's confusing? You know its recalculations. If you want stable reputation you can bank on keeping, stick to asking and answering good questions ;)

Comment: @Gimby If you gain or lose reputation, it usually is not hundreds of points at the same moment. An example of how it is confusing: One minute I had access to some review queues, and then when I refreshed my page, I got an error saying I don't have enough rep. I though something broke until I realized my rep went back down.

Comment: I gained 1.3k since yesterday :0. However, the status bar here on the **meta** site still shows the old value... Perhaps it's this? https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

Comment: Just noticed it happened to me as well.
+1.8k rep for me (I was around 6k if I remember well)